# Depth Information and RGB Recoverable Conversion Method

Tags: python, image, image-processing, realsense

I am currently trying to do some machine learning tasks with depth information obtained using Intel® RealSense™ Depth Cameras.

I am investigating algorithms that can convert depth information into RGB images and recover the original depth information from the RGB images.

Intel has published an official method (https://dev.intelrealsense.com/docs/depth-image-compression-by-colorization-for-intel-realsense-depth-cameras). I tried it in Python, but it did not work and did not give the expected results, as if the branching formula listed was incorrect.

If anyone knows of any better way, I'd appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: @Bilal Thanks for the reply! But they seem to be discussing the frames they get from the SDK and their coloring and restoration.

In my case, I am working with a Numpy array obtained from a different wrapper, so the situation may be a bit different.

Comment: Please click [edit] and show the code you tried and also what results you got and why you believe they were incorrect. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.